Processing list in Dialogflow CX
My webhook returns the string list to the agent. I want to provide a sort of loop for each item in this list where the same pages are activated when the user selects the item. When returning from the iteration the list should be shortened by the corresponding item.
Is such scenarion is possible in Dialogflow CX? Does anybody gave an example of such construction?
Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
